How to properly delete data from a table and chain the deletion
I'm new to postgreSQL and I'm trying to delete a row from a table and then also delete the relevant data from another table and then the linking table; Im trying to learn while doing so im pretty sure what im doing is way wrong.
Its giving me an error:
update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "usertopantry_user_id_fkey" on table "usertopantry"

The userstopantry table looks like:
user_id : integer : NOT NULL true : Primary KEY: true DEFAULT nextval('usertopantry_user_id_seq'::regclass)

pantry_id: integer : NOT NULL true : Primary KEY: true DEFAULT 
nextval('usertopantry_pantry_id_seq'::regclass)

This is the code im running to try and DELETE from all sources when a user DELETES a user:
const deleteUser = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id)

  pool.query('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = $1', [id], (error, userResults) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    if(response) {
      pool.query('SELECT pantry_id FROM userstopantry WHERE user_id = $1', [id], (error, pantryResults) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error
        }

        pool.query('DELETE FROM pantries WHERE pantry_id = $1', [pantryResults.rows[0].pantry_id], (error, deletionResults) => {
          if (error) {
            throw error
          }
          pool.query('DELETE FROM userstopantry WHERE user_id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
              throw error
            }
            response.status(200).send(`User deleted with ID: ${id}`)
          })
        })
      })
    }
  })
}

Im using Node.js with pg.pool

This is not a Postgres issue, it is a SQL issue namely a failure in understanding how Foreign Keys work.  You are obviously deleting a parent(referenced) record in users that a child(referencing) record in userstopantry depends on. From here Create Table read the section starting REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ] .. for what your options are. You can have the child record(s) automatically deleted on the parent deletion, but think about that before you implement it.

I believe DELETE CASCASE is exactly what you're looking for. It will delete related rows in other tables automatically.
This is a good first article https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-delete-cascade/
